# How can I move images in android and creat an animation?

Tags: android-animation

I just started to program in Android, but I programed in java (OOP), so I need help -
I have an ImageButton in my xml file, and I have the java project which supposed to make the xml file do stuff, right?
So how can I make the ImageButton from the xml file to move - with run function? with threds? with paintComponent?

I tried to do something like that -

```
public class example1 extends Activity{
    ImageButton i=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.i1);
    int bottom=i.getBottom();
    int left=i.getLeft();
    int right=i.getRight();
    int top=i.getTop();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void run(){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) i.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom+1);
        i.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

But i dont know how to make it move according to time.